# Pytorch Cross Entropy Loss number Weights not matching number of classes?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong here, or if this is a bug in PyTorch. I'm trying to predict a number of classes - 5 in this case - but one of them, class 0, dominates over all others. This is the background class essentially and we aren't too interested in it. So I want to use the weights in the cross entropy function to emphasise the other 4 classes.

I was reading the documentation for the https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropyloss

... and it seems like the shape for the first argument tensor is (minibatch,C,d1​,d2​,...,dK​)

Happy with that. C is apparently the number of classes, which is 5 in my case. That would be 0 to 4 inclusive.

Now according to the docs "weight (Tensor, optional) – a manual rescaling weight given to each class. If given, has to be a Tensor of size C" - so that would be 5

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def loss_func(result, target) -> torch.Tensor:
    print(result.shape, target.shape)
    class_weights = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1,0, 1.0], dtype=torch.float16, device=result.device)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
    dense = target.to_dense().long().to(result.device)
    loss = criterion(result, dense)
    return loss
```

And the output I get is the following:

```
torch.Size([2, 5, 26, 150, 320]) torch.Size([2, 26, 150, 320])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oni/Projects/PhD/sea_elegance_multi/train_unet.py", line 213, in <module>
    train(args, model, train_data, test_data, optimiser, writer)
  File "/home/oni/Projects/PhD/sea_elegance_multi/train_unet.py", line 118, in train
    loss = loss_func(result, target_mask)
  File "/home/oni/Projects/PhD/sea_elegance_multi/train_unet.py", line 61, in loss_func
    loss = criterion(result, dense)
  File "/home/oni/.conda/envs/seaelegance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oni/.conda/envs/seaelegance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1120, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/home/oni/.conda/envs/seaelegance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2824, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: weight tensor should be defined either for all or no classes at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/SpatialClassNLLCriterion.cu:27
```

Now if I adjust the weight tensor to [0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] it works fine, or rather, I get NANs and have to add "ignore_index=0".

I'm using a batch size of 2, with 3D images 320x150x26 pixels in size. So [2, 5, 26, 150, 320] seems correct to me. I wonder if there is something I've missed or if there is a bug? I am using float16 through-out and that has caused NANs on occasion but I think " weight tensor should be defined either for all or no classes" seems like a bug.

Has anyone else had this at all? Perhaps I just need to upgrade my pytorch setup? I'm running 1.9.0

Here is a minimal viable example:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

def loss_func_works(result, target) -> torch.Tensor:
    print(result.shape, target.shape)
    class_weights = torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0, 1,0, 1.0], dtype=torch.float32, device=result.device)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
    dense = target.long().to(result.device)
    loss = criterion(result, dense)
    return loss


def loss_func_fails(result, target) -> torch.Tensor:
    print(result.shape, target.shape)
    class_weights = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1,0, 1.0], dtype=torch.float32, device=result.device)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
    dense = target.long().to(result.device)
    loss = criterion(result, dense)
    return loss


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = torch.tensor((), dtype=torch.float32)
    result = result.new_ones((2, 5, 26, 150, 320))
    target = torch.tensor((), dtype=torch.float32)
    target = target.new_ones((2, 26, 150, 320))

    loss_func_works(result, target)
    loss_func_fails(result, target)
```

Comment: I guess it would be best if you could supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we could help you better

Comment: Are you sure you only have 5 classes in your target tensor, please check.

Comment: Good point David - I've added that to my question.

Comment: I thought that Ivan. I checked and double checked my data and in no place do any numbers other than 0,1,2,3,4 appear in the data. What is true is that these classes don't always appear in every datum. Is that a problem? If so, this isn't mentioned in the docs.

Comment: You just used a , instead of a . so your weight vector has size 5/6 (Entry before the last one).

Comment: Good spot! Thanks!